# mysql query to find engine on duration

Tags: mysql

I have data like,

- engine - time
- on - 2015-02-16 10:00
- on - 2015-02-16 10:30
- on - 2015-02-16 10:40
- off - 2015-02-16 10:50
- off - 2015-02-16 11:00
- off - 2015-02-16 11:10
- on - 2015-02-16 11:20
- on - 2015-02-16 11:30
- on - 2015-02-16 11:40

I need a query to find the current status like "engine ON from 2015-02-16 11:20"

Comment: What's your table definition? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As per comments, previous attempt was *wrong*; trying again.)

```
SELECT @oo := engine FROM tbl ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;  -- get 'on'
SELECT @prev := time FROM tbl
        WHERE engine != @oo
        ORDER BY time DESC  LIMIT 1;       -- 2015-02-16 11:10 (last 'off')
SELECT CONCAT(
          'engine ',
          UCASE(engine),
          ' from ',
          time )   AS 'current status'
    FROM tbl
    WHERE engine = @oo
      AND time > @prev
    ORDER BY time ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: the requirement is last engine status ie 'on/off' and if 'on' engine is on from time, if off engine is off from time. here status is engine is 'on' from '2015-02-16 11:20'

Comment: Show me data for which my code gives the wrong answer.

Comment: for the above data output should be "engine ON from 2015-02-16 11:20". With this query the output is "engine ON from 2015-02-16 11:40".

Comment: Works fine. Thank You.